# I think I'm out of scope with this

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question.  I'm thinking it's OOB.  I want to know if you think it is or not.  pasting the question and looking for feedback of whether or not it should get flagged if I did post it.

TIA

## Here's the question....but it's not a question

**I'm making a claim**

I have no facts to back my claim.  No citations, no evidence.

Yet, I believe that ***HD VTwins produce some of the highest low RPM torque values in the industry and even amongst cars, per cc.***

I am looking for a proof and facts, mathemagic if you will, to either prove or disprove my claim.

***I'll give XXX Rep*** to the individual that proves or disproves my claim with facts and not forum based citations.

If you feel like your math is beyond the scope of me and the community, tell us like we are five.  Break down your magical math and explain every little tiny piece of it.  Make us smarter.

So, to clarify, **this is my claim,** that you will either prove or disprove.

**HD VTwins produce some of the highest low RPM torque values per cc in the industry and possibly, among cars.**

**I cannot open the question with a bounty.  SE won't let me.  So I will get the question in the mix and assign the bounty to it after the three days and award the best answer to the best answer.**

***I'm really hoping this doesn't get flagged as out of scope***

Comment: So what are you after? Proof that HD engines have highest torque /cc or proof for *why* they have the highest torque/cc?

Comment: either way.  I'm making a claim that they do.  I don't care what the outcome is.

Comment: This is a good question ... should not be flagged.

Comment: I think that when you ask the question _you_ need to provide a good resource showing how much power an HD V-Twin can make, and define an RPM threshold for comparison.  Also specify that you're not considering Diesel (assume you're not).

Comment: good advice.  I'll incorporate that into the 'question' along with what bob posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should ask the question as a question.

Here's my hypothesis: HD Vtwins are totes awezomzors!

Question: is there evidence to support or refute this hypothesis?

Bounty: to the best data, for or against.

Comment: yes, that's much better.  TY for the guidance.